# Compiling Qt 5, getting warning "The build will most likely fail."

Tags: windows, qt, visual-studio-2008, build, qt5

I'm following [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) on compiling Qt 5 on Windows, using Visual Studio 2008 as the compiler.

When running `configure.bat` I get a warning - `The build will most likely fail.`

This is the complete command:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

This is an excerpt of configure.bat's output:

```
Running configuration tests...
WARNING: The DirectX SDK could not be detected:
  There is no Direct X SDK installed or the environment variable "DXSDK_DIR" is
not set.
Disabling the ANGLE backend.

WARNING: Using OpenGL ES 2.0 without ANGLE.
Specify -opengl desktop to use Open GL.
The build will most likely fail.
```

What should I do to avoid this warning? Should I specify `-opengl`, or should I install Direct X SDK?

**Edit**

The build (I ran `nmake`) did fail complaining that `GLES2/gl2.h` is missing:

```
c:\workspace\qt5source\qt5\qtbase\include\qtgui\../../src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h(82) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLES2/gl2.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you want to stay cross-platform, or are you only targeting Windows?

Comment: I'm only targeting Windows.

Comment: Does your target (and build) system support full OpenGL (i.e. not OpenGL ES)?

Comment: I have no idea. All I can say is I'm using the VS2008 toolchain. Not sure if it supports full OpenGL.

Comment: It's a hardware requirement rather than software one, your toolchain will support both.  What graphics card have you got?  If you don't have one, does your processor have one built into it?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm compiling Qt5, not running it. Why would I need a graphics card to compile a program that uses it? The program might fail to run, but it would still compile if headers and libs are there, right?

Comment: You've misunderstood, I'm trying to work out if your system supports OpenGL.  Qt seems fall back to using OpenGL ES unless specified.

Comment: I should have also asked if you are planning on using the 3D stuff of Qt, or any graphical hardware acceleration?

Comment: Ok, my video card is ATI Radeon HD 5570. And no, I won't be using any 3D stuff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OpenGL ES is a cut down version of the OpenGL specification aimed at smartphones and tablets, [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) provides the ability for OpenGL ES API calls to be converted to DirectX equivalents.

Unless you plan on creating apps that target OpenGL ES platforms *and* Windows, just go with passing `-opengl desktop` to `configure`.  Otherwise you will need to get hold of the DirectX SDK to enable ANGLE support.